# Calculating area of overlapping polygons using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, area, overlapping-features

In ArcGIS, I have a shapefile for a pipeline and another for plots of land that the pipeline shapefile touches and I was wondering if there is an obvious way to calculate the area that the pipeline covers within each of the individual polygons for the land plots shapefile.

Comment: Generally pipelines are modeled as lines in GIS, do you want the length of line that passes through a land plot?  Or do you actually want 'area' taking into account the width of the pipeline/trench?

Comment: @DMusketeer - Good point! I think in either scenario, an [intersect](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000p000000) would be the first step before creating a new field to calculate the length/area of the line/polygon.

Comment: @Joseph Intersect is probably the easiest way to go for this user, especially if it is a one off.  I work in pipelines and would use linear referencing tools to manage the data better.  It is a bit more complicated though.

Comment: Or do you mean something more like easements/RoW when you refer to area?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I am including a working area around the pipeline so it is a polygon. I really only want to know how much of the land in each plot/polygon will be taken up by the pipeline area that crosses it.

Answer (score 1):

If the pipeline is a line feature class use [buffer tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) to create a polygon. Then use [intersect tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm) with pipeline polygon and land plots as inputs. The resulting polygon will be the areas of overlap between the inputs.

[image]